# Is there a way to generate a Google Doc from HTML via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, google-apps-script, google-apps

Title pretty much says it all. ATM I've managed to $.post to a pre-defined Spreadsheet and have that replace some values in an existing Docs template, but unfortunately this doesn't fully meet my needs - generating a Google Doc from HTML via Javascript

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"doesn't fully meet my needs"* ... nobody is going to guess what those are. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: Edited the question, thank you

Comment: From the question, it sounds like you have data going from HTML > Spreadsheet > Document, so what is the problem? Posting some code will help, too.

Comment: @Brian The problem is the approach is kind of clunky and only works well if I'm replacing text inside a pre-made template - I'm searching for a more flexible solution that would allow me to be more dynamic eg. use tables with variable rows and styles. As of now it seems I just need to dive deeper in to the DocumentApp documentation on Google, but I'm sure if there was a way to send over pure HTML I could be a lot quicker in getting what I need. Code is irrelevant at this stage as my current solution doesn't come close to the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Google services you will need (Api already exist there's no shortcuts) :

[Sheets](https://developers.google.com/drive/)

[Drive](https://developers.google.com/sheets/)

and this is first step :

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?

Heres you will create new project and enable what you want. 
 This is embedded viewer schema .

Just follow instructions and online demos and examples.